# Smarty's template inheritence and img src attribut

Tags: php, smarty, image, src

Is there a way to make Smarty convert **src** & **href** attributs values to the correct URL when using template inheritence

exmple:

**file: web/tpl/layout.tpl**

```
<img src="../img/logo.png" />
{block name=content}{/block}
```

**file: index.tpl**

```
{extends file="web/tpl/layout"}
{block name=content} home page content here{/block}
```

**file: dir/index.tpl**

```
{extends file="../web/tpl/layout"}
{block name=content} an other page content here{/block}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should define your base url and use that in your src and href:

```
<img src="{$baseurl}/img/logo.png" />
{block name=content}{/block}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i did this and it worked `<img src="/{$SUBDIR}/web/img/logo_este.png"/>` with my project being located in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/fcest` and $SUBDIR = "fcest/"